# Which Atom system images should I chose from API 26 in Android Studio?

Tags: android, sdk

Android Studio 2.3.3 SDK Manager API 26 has 4 Atom system images:

- Android TV
- Android Wear
- Google Play
- Google API

Which one should I use?

[API 26 SDK Manager screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BWYiK.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what platform you have designed your app for. I would guess try running it on Google API first, and see if that works